# Keeping multicast messages on my machine

Tags: python, linux, sockets, routes

My code does the following:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 0)
self.sock.sendto("hello", ('225.0.0.10', 1026))
```

I have an application running on my machine which I wish to test and which is accepting messages on port 1026. This application is correctly receiving my message. However, how do I ensure that my message does not leave my computer, spamming other machines? I am running on linux.

Comment: Is this for testing? The entire point of multicast is usually to send packets to multiple machines. Can you use 127.0.0.1 instead of 225.0.0.10, which would prevent the packet from being sent to your local router?

Comment: @chepner Yes, this is for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a route to self. Possibly you have to use `sudo` / become root for that.

`route add 225.0.0.10 gw 127.0.0.1`

Alternatively you could always configure your application-tester to use `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: This works but can it be done without changing the routing table, by instead configuring the socket that I am creating in my python script?

Comment: configure your socket to send to 127.0.0.1, should work as well